# Why is there no 64-bit release of the Netbook Edition?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, 64-bit

Why is there not a 64-bit version of Ubuntu netbook edition around? Now that there are 64-bit Atoms around, I think it would make sense (more CPU registers etc)..(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it's probably because the 64-bit Atoms are a more recent phenomenon, and the Ubuntu folks just haven't gotten around to it. However, if you really wanted a 64-bit version of the Netbook Remix, I think you could get it - as long as you're willing to do a bit of extra work.

If you downloaded and installed the [Minimal 64-bit Ubuntu installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and then installed the `ubuntu-netbook` and `ubuntu-netbook-default-settings` packages, you would effectively have a 64-bit version of the Netbook Edition.

I've always run into a couple "interesting" issues when installing from the minimal system, but I think that might be your best bet until they release the official version.